# A Strange Problem with Qt Creator with I build a simple project

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, qt-creator, qmake

Here is my Qt Creator Version:

[image: Qt Creator Version]

this project is very simple, just contains two classes like this:
Project structure
[image: Project structure]

when I build this project , it will report an error like this: **multiple target patterns. Stop**
and link to a Makefile and point to an area like this:

> qrc_stylesheet.cpp: ../Lighting/stylesheet.qrc \ 
>           D:/Qt/5.14.0/mingw73_64/bin/rcc.exe \ 
>           Active\ code\ page:\ 65001 \   
>           ../Lighting/qss/login.qss 
>       D:\Qt\5.14.0\mingw73_64\bin\rcc.exe -name stylesheet ..\Lighting\stylesheet.qrc -o qrc_stylesheet.cpp

several times before, I delete the text **D:/Qt/5.14.0/mingw73_64/bin/rcc.exe \ 

        Active\ code\ page:\ 65001 \   

        ../Lighting/qss/login.qss** 


miraculous, it works!! however, everytime I rebuild the project it will append on the Makefile again >_<
but last time I rebuild the project again, it didn't work.I'm very confused by the problem, can anyone help me out..

Comment: please, don't link images but copy the text to your question instead

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new version of Qt, and the problem was perfectly sovled.I thought may be some thing wrong with Qt itself

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same symptoms.
Deleting the active code page solves the problem.
But I don't know why the problem occurs.

Even if I install a new version of At, the same case occurs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35291527)